# "ps" output and comments

Tags: ps, proc

I'm pretty sure you can't do this but maybe someone has some weird hack.

Is there a way to get comments (#blahblah) to show up in ps output?

My problem is that I have a script -- let's call it "myscript.sh" -- that is not very descriptive.

I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
 ./myscript.sh #Running on 10.10.45.10
```

and have ps output the comment line, instead of just saying "myscript.sh"

The only way I can think of hacking around it would be to place the comment in a variable, grep out "myscript.sh" PID and then read that var from /proc/PID/environ. But that's very ugly, and requires root.

Comment: Does myscript.sh accept command line arguments? If not, `/myscript.sh Running on 10.10.45.10` should work. If yes, can you edit it to handle a special argument too? If yes, `/myscript.sh -c 'Running on 10.10.45.10'` should work, just instruct it to not fail when seeing `-c` arguments.

Comment: You don't need to be running as root to access **your own** processes. `ps` (at least the one from the `procps` package) has also option the `e` which displays the environment right away, you can also parse output of that (unfortunately the environment is not separated from the command name, which is lame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With zsh, you could do something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
(($+ARG0_SET)) || ARG0_SET= ARGV0="#Running on 10.10.45.10" exec zsh "$0" "$@"
ps -f -p "$$"
```

Which when run gives:

```
~$ ./a
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas 20157  8822  0 21:51 pts/1    00:00:00 #Running on 10.10.45.10 ./a
```

The `ksh93` equivalent would be:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
((${#ARG0_SET})) || ARG0_SET=yes exec -a "#Running on 10.10.45.10" ksh93 "$0" "$@"
ps -f -p "$$"
```